# Поменять код HTML через gulp

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, less

Вопрос может дурацкий, но есть такая проблема:
У меня есть 2 папки **src** и **dist**. В одной исходники, которые я редактирую, в другой то, что на выходе после сборщика **gulp**. Хочу использовать **less**, установил плагин **gulp-less** для того чтобы компилировать в css на выходе, но получается что на выходе файл компилируется и превращается в css файл, но при этом строчка подключения в **index.html** не меняется и путь ведет к файлу, которого нету

gulp файл

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');


gulp.task('less', function() {
 return gulp.src('src/style.less')
   .pipe(less())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})

gulp.task('html', ['less'], function() {
 return gulp.src('src/index.html')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

разметка

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class ="header">
  <div class="header__block">
   Primarily, in the Middle East (especially the Ottoman Empire), a divan was a long seat formed of a mattress laid against the side of the room, upon the floor or upon a raised structure or frame, with cushions to lean against.
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

надеюсь правильно сформулировал вопрос

Comment: Вариант сразу писать `dist/style.css` вместо `style.less` не подходит?

Comment: в index.html сразу прописывайте style.css, а чтобы сразу смотреть изменения рекомендую browser-sync

либо, используйте плагин gulp-replace

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace

Comment: т.е подключать less.js всетаки надо? я думал чисто с помощью плагина для галп сделать

Comment: @ArtemPalamarchuk воспользуйтесь моей разработкой https://github.com/1000tech/web-starter-kit. Там по-умолчанию уже настроено взаимодействие.